# Number of different binary search trees storing n distinct keys?

Tags: binary-trees, recursion, search-trees

How many different binary search trees are possible that store the values 1,2,...,n ?

So far I found a recursive formula for the number (by case distinction what's at the root):

$ T(n) = 2T(n-1) + \sum_{i=2}^{n-1}T(i-1)T(n-i), n > 1 $ and $ T(1) = 1 $

But I have no idea how to solve this recursion. Our task was only to find the recursion and I believe this to be a correct solution. But I am very interested in a closed formula of it. Can anyone link me to some resources/books or give a general hint on how it can be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to your recurrence is
$$ T(n) = \frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}, $$
also known as the Catalan numbers. The quickest way to find this is by computing a few elements of the sequence and using the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) to identify the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Any time you see something resembling a convolution, that suggests generating functions as a method. Convolutions are things that look like $\sum_x f(x)f(\overline{x})$, where $\overline{x}$ denotes some kind of "complement" or "opposite" of $x$.  Generating functions often turn convolutions into products.

Possible references are:

- Herbert S. Wilf, *generatingfunctionology*. 3rd edition, A. K. Peters, 2004. (A PDF of the second edition is available [from the author's website](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).)
- Philippe Flajolet and Robert Sedgewick, *Analytic Combinatorics*. Cambridge University Press, 2009. (PDF [on the first author's website](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf).)
- Our own [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2789/9550).